# How to override doResizeColumn in dojox.grid._Builder

Tags: dojo, overriding

How do I override doResizeColumn in dojox.grid._Builder.  I'm not sure how to handle it since its a method in variable dg._HeaderBuilder.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: which dojo version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override it for all instances, this could be done using `dojo/aspect`'s `around()` (see the [Refernece Guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/aspect.html) for further information) like this:

```
    define(["dojo/aspect"], function(aspect) {
        aspect.around(dojox.grid._builder, "doResizeColumn", function(originalDoResizeColumn) {
            return function(/* needs the original signature(params) of the original doResizeColumn */) {
                // Your code here
                /* you could call the original doResizeColumn (which you 'kinda override' here) anytime if you want just here
                 * originalDoResizeColumn(...);
                 */
                // and even do sth. after it.
            };
        });
    });
```

**EDIT:**
For dojo `V1.6` this is kinda experimental, but you can have a try:

```
    dojo.require("dojox.lang.aspect");
    var aop = dojox.lang.aspect; //define the namespace...

    aop.advise(dojox.grid._Builder, 'doResizeColumn', {
        around: function( /*originalparameters*/ ) {

            // your code here
            // the original coll looks as sth. like the following i dunno exactly

            aop.proceed( /*fitting params*/ ); 
            // some other code after it maybe...
        }
    });
```

Have a look at [this interesting blog entry](http://lazutkin.com/blog/2008/may/18/aop-aspect-javascript-dojo/) or this [sort of documentation](http://higginsforpresident.net/api/dojox/lang/aspect.html) of `dojox.lang.aspect` for further Information. maybe `dojox.lang.aspect.advise`'s `before` would fit your needs better. See the links above for that.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately (and I should have stated it in the question), I'm using Dojo 1.6 and can't upgrade at this time.  aspect is not available in Dojo 1.6

Comment: then the only way i know isn't exactly override: you could connect your code within a callback-function to a instance of _Builder like `dojo.connect(yourinstance,'doResizeColumn',function(){yourCallbackFunction();});`. It'll be executed after the original `doResizeColumn()` was called on the instance.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work.  I'm trying to set minColWidth based on inDrag state so I need to set minColWidth before calling original doResizeColumn().

Comment: Thanks nozzleman for your help. I attempted the experimental Dojo 1.6 code you suggested but I could never get the code to trigger.  We plan to upgrade to Dojo 1.8 in coming months so I'll attempt this again at that time.